# No audio flash movies

Tags: sound, flash, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No audio in Adobe Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67348/no-sound-in-flash-11-10)

I've installed natty a few days ago and I'm experience some issues with the audio. Basically, I'm not able to listen anything coming from flash movies (such as youtube).
This happen with both chromium and firefox (I use only the first one) and the errore I get in the stdout is:

ALSA lib pcm.c:2109:(snd_pcm_open_conf) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so

I don't know how to fix it. I found somewhere to install native x64 flash plugins, but somebody says it is not advisable. I didn't get this kind of issues with 10.10 I've gotten before of natty.
Hence, what am I supposed to do?
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try installing *libasound2* and *libasound2-plugins*.

```
sudo aptitude install libasound2 libasound2-plugins
```

--Edit--
Installing *flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound* may solve this problem as well.

```
sudo aptitude install flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound
```

Comment: libasound2* were already installed and there's no flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound, but flashplugin-nonfree instead. Installing it, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.webgapps.org/tutorials/firefox/troubleshooting/flash-issues-and-solutions

Comment: no audo at all...
Only thing I hear now (after installing pulseaudio) is the drums before the login.

Comment: I reconfigured pulseaudio and I can hear everything, but flash. I still have the issue!