# No audio in Adobe Flash

Tags: 11.10, sound, flash

I am on 11.10 64bit and I have installed flash from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/.

I had downloaded `install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz` and moved `libflashplayer.so` to `~/.mozilla` and `~/.mozilla/plugins`

I also have OSS installed because alsa does not work for me. I generally follow steps mentioned at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound and everything works fine.

But for 11.10, flash has no sound. I am not sure if that is OSS problem.

Comment: There is a adobe-flashplugin package on the partners repository, have you tried it instead of the manual download ?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I forgot to mention that. Same problem with the above package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem in Ubuntu Oneric Ocelot 11.10 32bit. I was able to hear sound from flash movies, but it would work in all other applications and even Pandora radio.

I was able to fix it by doing

```
$ mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse.bak
```

then logging out and logging back in.

I think some settings file was botched by an upgrade to pulse, which the flash player depends on.

For more information, check out:
http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3118895.msg277490#msg277490

**Update:**

I've noticed that after updating my flash player today that I am no longer having this issue.

If you have performed the fix mentioned above and were having issues with your sound icon remaining a flat line and needing to control your volume using `alsamixer`, this update appeared to fix that issue for me as well.